# Error when attempting to change tensor shape in keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to change the shape and the content of the tensor in a keras model. Tensor is the output of a layer and has

`shape1=(batch_size, max_sentences_in_doc, max_tokens_in_doc, embedding_size)`

and I want to convert to

`shape2=(batch_size, max_documents_length, embedding_size)`

suitable as input of the next layer. Here sentences are made of tokens, and are zero-padded so every sentence has `length=max_tokens_in_sentence`. 
In detail:

1. I wanto to concatenate all the sentences of a batch taking only the nonzero part of the sentences;
2. then I zero-pad this concatenation to a `length=max_document_length`.

So passing from `shape1` to `shape2` is not only a reshape as mathematical operations are involved.

I created the function `embedding_to_docs(x)` that iterates on the tensor of shape1 to transform it into shape2. I call the function using a Lambda layer in the model, it works in debug with fictious data, but when I try to call it during the build of the model an error is raised:

`Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

```
def embedding_to_docs(x):
    new_output = []
    for doc in x:
        document = []
        for sentence in doc:
            non_zero_indexes = np.nonzero(sentence[:, 0])
            max_index = max(non_zero_indexes[0])
            if max_index > 0:
                document.extend(sentence[0:max_index])
        if MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH-len(document) > 0:
            a = np.zeros((MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH-len(document), 1024))
            document.extend(a)
        else:
            document = document[0:MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH]
        new_output.append(document)

    return np.asarray(new_output)

...

# in the model:
tensor_of_shape2 = Lambda(embedding_to_docs)(tensor_of_shape1)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function), which allows you to switch from the graph mode (used by Keras) to the eager mode (where it is possible to iterate over tensors like in your function).

```
def to_docs(x):
  return tf.py_function(embedding_to_docs, [x], tf.float32)

tensor_of_shape2 = Lambda(to_docs)(tensor_of_shape1)
```

Note that the code run within your `embedding_to_docs` must be written in tensorflow eager instead of numpy. This means that you'd need to replace some of the numpy calls with tensorflow. You'd surely need to replace the return line with:

```
return tf.convert_to_tensor(new_output)
```

Using numpy arrays will stop the gradient computation, but you are likely not interested in gradient flowing through the input data anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot, this seems a simple and elegant way. But, I need a ndarray at the end, and I think 'tf.convert_to_tensor(new_output)' will return a tf tensor,

Comment: Keras model and it's Lambda layer (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) operate on tensors, because ndarrays do not implement gradient backpropagation. Even if the Lambda layer allows you to return ndarray it will be converted to tensor (I am not sure about this). You can go back to ndarrays when you either evaluate the tensor (`x.eval()`) or using model's `predict`.

Comment: Ok, I've just changed the Lambda function and now it returns a tensor, no more a ndarray. The model compiles, but when I call the `model.fit()` another error is raised: `ValueError: An operation has 'None' for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.` It seems the problem you hinted, but why? And how to fix it?

Comment: It's difficult to judge from a single layer. It could be that you have some non-differential operation in a different layer. Alternatively a layer that precedes this Lambda layer requires the gradient. You try to make this layer differentiable by replacing numpy and standard python functions with tensorflow functions, e.g. `np.nonzero(z)` -> `tf.greater(z, 0)` (you would need `import tensorflow as tf`).